# What is the difference between a node and property in Neo4J.

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How can we decide between a node and property while preparing Neo4J schema. for example if we are having a employee table in SQL

```
   Name     location   designation
   ----     --------    --------
    Ravi     Hyd.        SE
    Rahul    Pune        Manager
```

If we want to prepare same schema in Neo4j, on what basis we can differentiate nodes and properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodes are the actual entries of your data (comp. to table rows)

Nodes have properties (comp. to columns in a table row)

So you would have a node with the label "Employee" and properties according to your columns *name*, *location* and *designation*.

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your response, can we put location as separate node so that i will contain parameters like city,PIN code ..etc ... is it recommonded?

Comment: Yes, if location is associated with multiple employees, it would be a way of normalizing the data. But else I wouldn't do it.